# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure & database disappeared & sql cmd line auto close

Tags: spring-data-jpa

After running CCleaner and trying to debug a fix an Oauth password encryption type error, I have this error:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException:
>   Communications link failure

and all the local databases seemed to have disappeared
[image]

I tried to create a new database with MYSQL command line. After entering my password, there was a error and the window closed.

I have tried many solutions to debug the errors e.g. setting

```
compile('org.hibernate:hibernate-core')
compile('org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager')
```

to resolve an EntityFactory error which lead to this error I think.
I also tried killing the process on port 3306. But I couldn't think of any other options. Any suggestions for next steps would be...?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently mysql service stopped working at some point without me realizing. The solution was going to Start -> type 'service.msc' -> run mysql80 (stands for mysql version 8.0 I think).